# How can I restrict an extension's access to specific domains in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

Google Chrome has this feature.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfrWs.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xdfzj.png

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do that as of February 2021.

Reference: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1497075